# random e-mail on orders without user e-mail adress

Tags: email, magento

if i take an order manually in Magento Backend without depositing an e-mail adress for the customer, Magento is creating a random one for this order.

But where does it come from or what is the sense of that? My problem here is that i'm recieving an error by mailerdemon because that e-mail does not exist.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check http://yourdomain.com/index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/customer/ under "Options for creating new customer". There you can set the custom domain used for new customers. Setting that to, for example, the free catch all email service mailinator.com should get rid of your errors.